# jQuery Tokeninput dropdown is under Colorbox window

Tags: drop-down-menu, colorbox, jquery-tokeninput, loopj

I have got a problem with Loopj's jQuery Tokeninput inside Jack Moore's Colorbox window. The problem is that dropdown of Tokeninput shows under Colorbox window, as on screenshot below:

[image: Dropdown under colorbox window]

I think that the problem could be with this code inside [tokeninput library](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/src/jquery.tokeninput.js) (lines 343-347):

```
// The list to store the dropdown items in
var dropdown = $("<div>")
    .addClass(settings.classes.dropdown)
    .appendTo("body")
    .hide();
```

because it is appended to body, not to colorbox window.

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

PS. I am using this lib also outside colorbox window, so appending it to colorbox probably will be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to fix this issue by altering the z-index of the TokenInput's dropdown.

The z-index of a Colorbox is 9999, the default value for the TokenInput is lower than that.

Depending on which TokenInput version you're using - if it supports the `z-index` parameter, you could alter the value with that on initialisation. e.g.

```
$('#myID').tokenInput("http://sourceurl.com",
                       {
                           zindex: 100001
                       }
```

Else if it's an earlier version, try altering the value for `div.token-input-dropdown` in the `token-input.css` file.

I've put in a [pull request](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/pull/678) for this issue on GitHub, but sadly, the project now seems to have sunk back into inactivity.